# Weird behavior using interface parameters

Tags: go

When i call a function with an `interface{}` parameters with a `*[]interface{}`, the behavior is expected, but when I call the function with `[]interface{}`, and then use the parameter with `&` it doesn't work why ?

```golang
func routeWarehouses(engine *gin.Engine) {
    var test []database.Warehouses
    router.GET("/", genericReads(test))
}

func genericReads(i interface{}) func(c *gin.Context) {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        // When i call genericReads with `test`
        //println(reflect.TypeOf(i).Kind()) // Slice
        //println(reflect.TypeOf(i).Elem().Kind()) // Struct

        // When i call genericReads `&test`
        //println(reflect.TypeOf(i).Kind()) // Ptr
        //println(reflect.TypeOf(i).Elem().Kind()) // Slice
        //println(reflect.TypeOf(i).Elem().Elem().Kind()) // Struct

        // When I call database.Reads with `i` ( passed as `&test` ), It's works, I get all rows of the Model otherwise
        // When I call database.Reads with `&i` ( passed as `test` ), It doesn't work ( I get `unsupported destination, should be slice or struct` )
        if err := database.Reads(&i, database.Warehouses{}); err != nil {
            utils.R500(c, err.Error())
            return
        }

        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, i)
    }
}
```

```golang
func Reads(i interface{}, column ColumnSpell) error {
    if err := DB.Debug().Find(i).Error; err != nil {
        return errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("Cannot reads %s: %s", column.Plural(), err.Error()))
    }

    return nil
}
```

PS: Maybe this come directly from Gorm ?

Comment: Can you define "the behavior is expected" and "it doesn't work"? What is the specific problem you're having?

Comment: You rarely ever want a pointer to an interface. Your code here also never uses `*[]interface{}`. The only pointer you have here is `&i` which is `*interface{}`

Comment: If by `*[]interface{}` you actually mean `*[]database.Warehouses` (which are distinct types), then yes, you need to use that. You always must decode into a pointer, so the correct solution here is to use `&test`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because a slice is already a pointer (https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types).

So to set a pointer to a slice is setting a pointer to a pointer. So just remeber if you are dealing with slices they are pointers to arrays.

More information how the slices are used as a pointer are here: https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#slices